# Tool to list all current Windows 10 Hotkeys?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, sysadmin

I tried *"Windows Hotkey Explorer"* (WHE) and it exploded in my face in a spectacular fashion. (Do NOT ever run this if you are on Windows 8 or higher. It will just PRESS each and every hotkey. You will end up with a zoomed, flipped, narrator-activated, unusable desktop.)

So. Is there something that does what WHE tries to do that actually works in Windows 10?

I have googled without success.

#### Related links

- [This question](https://superuser.com/questions/11308/how-can-i-determine-which-process-owns-a-hotkey-in-windows) suggests either WHE or Delphi. WHE fails terribly on Win 10. And I don't have Delphi.
- [This question](https://superuser.com/questions/661961/what-other-tool-is-using-my-hotkey) suggests WHE. WHE fails terribly on Win 10.
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829007/find-out-what-process-registered-a-global-hotkey-windows-api/834661) suggests either WHE or Delphi. WHE fails terribly on Win 10. And I don't have Delphi.
- Only dead links [here](http://forum.sysinternals.com/hotkey-finder_topic12257.html).
- WHE is not listed [at AlternativeTo.Net](https://alternativeto.net/browse/search?q=windows+hotkey+explorer).

#### Update 2016-06-07. Why do I care?

Yesterday I spent about an hour looking for the program that caused notepad to no longer accept <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>. Normally that hotkey opens the "Print" dialog. Yesterday it did nothing at all.

It turned out that the QNAP NAS utility `QfinderPro.exe` had somehow grabbed that key combination. As soon as I had stopped that program <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> started working again.

And I would like a tool that could tell me what hotkey is registered by what program. Basically I am looking for a version of WHE that works on Windows 10.

Answer (score 12):

[NirSoft HotKeysList](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/hot_keys_list.html) will tell you that a hotkey is in use, but unfortunately:

- it is also completely unsuitable for the OP's purpose (Windows 10), as the software explains: "This utility works on any version of Windows, starting from Windows 2000 and up to Windows 8."
- It will not tell you by what process.  It could be quite valuable if you paired this with the troubleshooting processes recommended in [this SuperUser link.](https://superuser.com/a/1096520/487385)

The software is free for use, as are most NirSoft offerings.

[image]

(originally recommended by @obe)

Comment: It is listing hotkeys for me on windows 10. Tough I'm unsure it is listing them all.

Comment: HotKeysList works on Windows 10 Home.

Comment: Note that this does not show hotkeys bound to F13-F24

Answer (score 3):

The tool [OpenARK](https://github.com/BlackINT3/OpenArk) worked great for me. It is simple to use for this purpose, and works on recent OS versions like Win 10/11.

Under "Kernel" tab, "System Hotkey" page, you can find all registered hotkeys and corresponding processes, and also can delete the messed ones. Remember to click "Enter KernelMode" button first.

Right-click an hotkey to delete it.

[image: OpenARK]

Comment: On Windows 11 the Hotkey column remains empty (yes, I have entered Kernel mode).